# Calculate buffer distance by known area

Tags: geometry

I have a rectangle with a known area *S1* and known sides *A* and *B*, I need to make new rectangle around the first with area *S2* by applying buffer operation to the first rectangle. How can I calculate buffer distance (*D*) to solve this problem?

Comment: You really should clarify what you mean by "buffer operation" and "buffer distance", but see if my answer corresponds to what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unfamiliar with what you mean by buffer distance, so I'm going to start by showing a general approach, then narrow things down by assuming you want a square "buffer" between each pair of corresponding vertices.

Let's say the two concentric rectangles are situated symmetrically. Let the width of the inner rectangle be $A$ and its length be $B$. For symmetry, the inner rectangle has to be centered both vertically and horizontally within the new larger rectangle. See image. [image]

So the corresponding dimensions of the outer rectangle will be $A + 2x$ and $B+2y$. You want the product to be $S_2$.

To achieve a square "buffer" between each of the vertices (corners), you can let $x=y$, so you can now write the equation:

$(A+2x)(B+2x) = S_2$

$AB + 4x^2 + 2x(A+B) = S_2$

And since $AB = S_1$,

$4x^2 + 2(A+B)x + (S_1 - S_2) = 0$

You can solve this using the quadratic formula (discarding the negative root) to give:

$$x = \frac{-2(A+B) + \sqrt{4(A+B)^2 + 16(S_2 - S_1)}}{8} = \frac{ \sqrt{(A+B)^2 + 4(S_2 - S_1)} - (A+B)}{4}$$

and here the $x$ should represent the buffer distance you refer to.

Comment: Yes. It is exactly what I needed! Thanks